# python selenium - how can i find out exactly when an alert happens?

Tags: python, django, selenium, firefox

I want to find out when an alert happens so I can automatically accept. I've placed `self.driver.switch_to.alert.accept()` in various places in the code but I always get a `selenium.common.exceptions.NoAlertPresentException`. When I don't place it anywhere I get an `selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedAlertPresentException`. When I use expected_conditions I get a `selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException`. I don't know what to do at this point. Can anyone help?

Python/Django Backend. Using Selenium (Firefox)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a method for that, but if you know it will happen, make a while loop with try-catch block until the alert happens

Answer (score 0):

It's better to have **explicit Wait** in this situation :

`Alert's` are **known** to us, right ?

If you perform `let's say 5 steps manually` and then you were expecting an alert to pop up then automate the exact same steps.

Let's talk about the **different scenario** where there's a `user name Input field` and down to that we have a `submit button`, Now if you do not give anything in that input field and click on Submit, you'd get an **Alert** that will say "`Hey ! you must enter a user name in order to proceed`".

Now in the same situation, When we will automate this scenario, perform the exact steps :

1. **Python - Selenium** will not enter anything in `User Name input field`.
2. **Python - Selenium** will directly `click on Submit button`.
3. **Python - Selenium** will expect a **Alert** to pop up, and `switch over` to it like this :

   alert_pop_up = driver.switch_to.alert
   alert_pop_up.accept()

In most of the cases this should work, But there's no harm including `Explicit wait`.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.alert_is_present())
```